# jQuery Autocomplete - Modify Menu Items With Javascript

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'd like to modify the text that appears for the autocomplete items. I'm updating it in the DOM using javascript but when I trigger the autocomplete the old labels still appear.

For example, the autocomplete menu shows this when trigger:

- 1st Item
- 2ns Item
- 3rd Item

And I modify the ui-menu-item item to show

- First Item
- Second Item
- Third Item

But the first set still appears. Can I refresh this somehow? I want my source to stay the same. I've tried the disable and enable it, or destroy, but it isn't working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you don't want to modify the DOM, instead modify the _renderMenu function to return the data you want since it's called every time the autocomplete menu is triggered.